# Need help on Bootstrap flip card positioning option

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need some help with a bootstrap flip card. I try to copy a Bootstrap flip card snipped from "https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/3161", which is working for me. When i hover it turns back but i need the option as a simple hyper link content as attached, currently it is displaying it as button. When you hover the Card Four you will see the button but i need as simple text hyperlinks

[image: Required Output]

```css
  body {
        color: #666;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #eeeeee;
      }
      h2 {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 5% 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
      }
      .cardBox {
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
        perspective: 800px;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        width: 20%;
      }
      .cardBox:hover .card {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      .card {
        background: #666666;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 250px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .card p {
        margin-bottom: 1.8em;
      }
      .card .front,
      .card .back {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0.8em 0.7em;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .card .front strong {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 100%;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding: 0 7px 4px 6px;
      }
      .card .back {
        transform: rotateY( 180deg);
      }
      .card .back a {
        padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 1px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
      }
      .card .back a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(1) .card .back {
        background: #ffcc00;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(2) .card .back {
        background: #1c87c9;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(3) .card .back {
        background: #ff6347;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card .back {
        background: #8ebf42;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(2) .card {
        -webkit-animation: giro 1.5s 1;
        animation: giro 1.5s 1;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(3) .card {
        -webkit-animation: giro 2s 1;
        animation: giro 2s 1;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card {
        -webkit-animation: giro 2.5s 1;
        animation: giro 2.5s 1;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes giro {
        from {
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        to {
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes giro {
        from {
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        to {
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .cardBox {
          margin-left: 2.8%;
          margin-top: 3%;
          width: 46%;
        }
        .card {
          height: 285px;
        }
        .cardBox:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 3%;
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .cardBox {
          width: 94.5%;
        }
        .card {
          height: 260px;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <body>
    <h2>Responsive Flip Cards</h2>
    <div class="boxesContainer">
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card One</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side One</h3>
            <p>Content in card one</p>
            <a href="www.gmail.com">Button 1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card Two</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side Two</h3>
            <p>Content in card two</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card Three</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side Three</h3>
            <p>Content in card three</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card Four</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side Four</h3>
            <p>Content in card four</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added below css styles to your stylesheet.

```
    .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card .back a {
        background: none !important;
      }

.cardBox:nth-child(4) .card .back a:hover {
        background: none !important;
      }
```

```css
body {
        color: #666;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #eeeeee;
      }
      h2 {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 5% 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
      }
      .cardBox {
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
        perspective: 800px;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        width: 20%;
      }
      .cardBox:hover .card {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      .card {
        background: #666666;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 250px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .card p {
        margin-bottom: 1.8em;
      }
      .card .front,
      .card .back {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: white;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0.8em 0.7em;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .card .front strong {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 100%;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding: 0 7px 4px 6px;
      }
      .card .back {
        transform: rotateY( 180deg);
      }
      .card .back a {
        padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 1px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
      }
      .card .back a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(1) .card .back {
        background: #ffcc00;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(2) .card .back {
        background: #1c87c9;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(3) .card .back {
        background: #ff6347;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card .back {
        background: #8ebf42;
        
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(2) .card {
        -webkit-animation: giro 1.5s 1;
        animation: giro 1.5s 1;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(3) .card {
        -webkit-animation: giro 2s 1;
        animation: giro 2s 1;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card {
        -webkit-animation: giro 2.5s 1;
        animation: giro 2.5s 1;
      }
      .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card .back a {
        background: none !important;
      }
     .cardBox:nth-child(4) .card .back a:hover {
        background: none !important;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes giro {
        from {
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        to {
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes giro {
        from {
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        to {
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .cardBox {
          margin-left: 2.8%;
          margin-top: 3%;
          width: 46%;
        }
        .card {
          height: 285px;
        }
        .cardBox:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 3%;
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .cardBox {
          width: 94.5%;
        }
        .card {
          height: 260px;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <body>
    <h2>Responsive Flip Cards</h2>
    <div class="boxesContainer">
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card One</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side One</h3>
            <p>Content in card one</p>
            <a href="www.gmail.com">Button 1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card Two</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side Two</h3>
            <p>Content in card two</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card Three</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side Three</h3>
            <p>Content in card three</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardBox">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <h3>Card Four</h3>
            <p>Hover to flip</p>
            <strong>&#x21bb;</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <h3>Back Side Four</h3>
            <p>Content in card four</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
            <a href="www.google.com">Button 4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. can we have it in a single line instead of splitting into 2 columns ?

Comment: First style is for normal view ans second style for mouse over

Comment: let me know if you have still doubt on this else mark the answer.